# Is there an USB adapter for the Earphones that will let you use both audio and mic simultaneously for a phone conversation?

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, headphones, microphone, ear-phones

I like the Apple Earphones (the iPhone headphone with audio, mic and remote) but I hate to keep plugging it on and off my Macbook Air. So I heard the only way to fix that is to buy a USB headphone so you can switch it on and off through software. Problem is that I like my Apple Earphones and I want to keep using it but now through USB. Is there a USB adapter that will work with the Earphones, in other words, that will **make both headphone and mic work at the same time for a phone conversation**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a USB adapter that directly takes the 4-pin 3.5mm connector that the Apple headset uses, but you could combine one of the many USB adapters with an adapter cable [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058DOWH6). That will convert the 4-pin connector to the separate 3-pin stereo & microphone connectors that are standard on PCs and should work with any USB adapters with an in & out. You will likely lose the volume and clicker controls on the headset.